# Scroll down a container with hidden overflow using jquery and css3 animation(flip vertically)

Tags: jquery, css, flipboard

I have a div which contains 20 lines of text.
I want to disable normal scroll and use flip effect (vertical) when I scroll down to see the text.

How can I do that using jQuery and CSS3 animation? 
Like Flipboard app for example.

Comment: Show initial code effort, this isn't a tutorial forum

Comment: Fixed some grammar and made edits to bring info closer into 1 sentence